# GTK 3 Eclipse error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-3.so.0

Tags: eclipse-cdt, gtk3, gtkmm3

I'm currently using Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0) to build a simple GTK 3 app. But after I build and then run the app, in Eclipse, I get the following error:

```
Debug/Test: error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-3.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

However, When I start the executable from a terminal, it starts just fine.

How can I resolve the shared library not found so I can run the app directly from within Eclipse?

Comment: So have you checked for the file `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0`? If you are running a 32 bit OS the path will be slightly different of course.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for that. Doing `ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0` gives me `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0 -> libgtk-3.so.0.1800.9`. Seems to be symlinked. As you can see, I'm on x64.